# How can I stop the Software Updater from nagging me to restart?

Tags: update-manager

Software Updater has installed some new software. I'm largely not interested in this fact as I just use this machine as a file server and watch everything on my tablet or Windows machine.

However, every time I connect to the machine, I see this:

[image]

This is a window with no close button with the "Restart" button selected by default so literally my next keypress will reboot the machine. This is almost as bad as Windows 8 rebooting whenever it wants to in order to apply updates.

I don't mind it installing updates as and when it wants to but I am only ever going to restart the machine when I want to restart it. How can I stop the Software Updater from nagging me to restart?

Comment: Move it to a different workspace and it won't even bother you(It's not a solution but just an escape)

Comment: Since you're using this as a server, why not just use [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server "Ubuntu Server download page")? It is intended to be used as a server, so the options for how it deals with updates are better suited for what you're doing.

Comment: Ubntu server also has updates.so the problem will continue.

Comment: What if you are using Ubuntu server with ubuntu-desktop added? then you have the same problem....

Comment: The Server edition allows more choices as far as installing updates.  I know for sure you can set it to only install updates manually which would solve the problem.  IIRC, you can also schedule it to run updates (and get reboots out of the way) at a certain time IE in the middle of the night.

Comment: Yes, if you add the desktop, you'd likely get to the same problem.  Ultimately, Ubuntu doesn't have a way to update certain files without a restart (EG the linux kernel), so if you don't want to be bothered with that message, the choices are 1) not install updates or 2) make sure they happen when a reboot is fine (either manually or via schedule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Launch **dconf editor** the way you want, maybe **Dash**
- Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for **hide-reboot-notification** and click next

[image]

- Click the checkbox and you are done!!!

Comment: This wont stop the window from coming up this will just make you ignore it. it's pretty much the same as moving it to another workspace.

Answer (score 5):

`dconf-editor` on Trusty doesn't have a hide-reboot-notifications option, but adding one with the following command appears to work:

```
dconf write /com/ubuntu/update-notifier/hide-reboot-notifications true
```

I tried using `gsettings set` but it complained that the key didn't exist. So far `dconf write` has stopped the reminder appearing, and the setting is now visible in `dconf-editor`.

Comment: `no-show-notifications` is also there, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xkill`.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 so that's what I'll use for the instructions.

Go to "system settings"->"keyboard"->"shortcuts" tab

In the left sidebar, select "custom shortcuts" and then press the "+" sign at the bottom to add one.

In the window that pops up, type `xkill` in both fields for name and command. Apply.
Click on the word "disabled" in the new shortcut and it will change to "New accelerator..."

Press your key combinations to activate xkill. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> .

Now, every time that window shows up (or a window hangs), just press the key combination and your cursor will change to an `X` shape. Click on the window to kill it. To cancel just right click anywhere.

**NOTE:** If you have any unsaved data in the window you select when doing this, it will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using:

```
killall update-manager
```

Anyway, my opinion is that you should disable the update manager at startup and in synaptic options (Configuration > repositories > updates > check updates automatically: never), since I agree, it is really annoying.

Of course, you WILL NEED to acquire the habit of do a manual update instead, or even schedule it with some tool (like cron). In order to be updated you must type regularly:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Answer (score 0):

Kill `software-updater` by running the below command,

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | grep software-updater | awk '{ print $2 }')
```