# Is there a way to suppress reboot prompts after system updates?

Tags: updates, xubuntu

I have an xubuntu server with a GUI that I need to keep running at all times.

After xubuntu prompts me install system updates, it sometimes prompts me to reboot the computer. I am using Ksplice Uptrack Manager so the reboots are not necessary.

Is there a way to make ubuntu/xubuntu never show the reboot prompts, so a colleague or I don't click the reboot button accidentally out of instinct?

Comment: Workaround: When the system update window pops up with notification of updates, that serves as my reminder that it's time to update manually using the terminal. I simply cancel the updates using the GUI, and drop into a terminal and update with apt-get. When updating from the terminal, there is no chance of accidentally rebooting.

Comment: What about these? http://askubuntu.com/q/403413/40581